# How to add validation rule dynamically to checkbox array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, jquery-validate

I am dynamically appending input fields to `div`. I wish to check if at least one `checkbox` is checked, for that I am adding `JQuery` validation rule dynamically to the array of input `checkbox` by using class.
HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="ans[]" value="opt_' + x + '" class="answer_check">
```

JavaScript:

```
 $(".answer_check").rules("add", {required: true, messages: {required: "Please select correct answer/s."}});
```

I am getting following error in console.

**Syntax error, unrecognized expression: `label[for='ans[]'], label[for='ans[]'] *, #ans[]-error`**

Comment: Your rule seems to be ok. Can you create a fiddle ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `$(".answer_check")` represents more than one element, then you cannot simply attach it to the `.rules()` method.  The developer designed these methods to only apply to the *first matched element* of the selector.

To attach to multiple elements you'll need to wrap it within a jQuery `.each()` instead.

```
$(".answer_check").each(function() {
    $(this).rules("add", {
        required: true, 
        messages: {
            required: "Please select correct answer/s."
        }
    });
});
```

Also, although you can share the same `name` throughout a *group* of checkbox or radio elements, each grouping **must** have a *unique* `name` or this plugin will not work properly.

Example:

```
Question 1:
<input type="radio" name="foo" value="yes" />yes
<input type="radio" name="foo" value="no" />no
<input type="radio" name="foo" value="maybe" />maybe

Question 2:
<input type="radio" name="bar" value="yes" />yes
<input type="radio" name="bar" value="no" />no
<input type="radio" name="bar" value="maybe" />maybe
```